Auth0 Authentication flow for Express and Websockets
I am developing an web application running on Node.js with Express, and I'm using Auth0 authentication via express-openid-connect to secure the routes.  That is all working great.
I need the client browser to open a Websocket (for WebRTC signalling, but that's kind of irrelevant here).  The server is already running a WSS server that requires JWT passed in the connection URL.  I have an Android app that's working with that WSS server.  I would like to use this same WSS server for the Website.  In order for the website to open the WebSocket, it's going to need the JWT accessToken.
In my express-openid-connect setup I'm requesting response_type 'code id_token', so I should have the JWT accessToken available within the Express router.  I've been researching secure methods to pass the accessToken to the client for use in WSS connection, but I haven't been able to determine the best method.
A couple questions:

I can't store the accessToken in an HTTP-only cookie, since I need client script to initiate the WSS connection.  What is the secure option that supports what I need to do?
Alternatively, I was thinking that I could use the session cookie (already in the header of the WSS upgrade request), pass that to the express server on the backend to get the JWT stored in express, and use that to allow the connection.  Does this make any sense?
Am I overthinking this?  The website that will open the websocket is a protected route - is it really adding any security to also authenticate the WSS connection?


If you can avoid sending access_token over the wire at all and strictly stick to sessions, you are 100% better off. Simpler and more secure.

So far I have gone with #2 and it is working.  I limited the express route to localhost and it succesfully returns an accessToken based on the appSession in the WSS upgrade header cookie.  Still interested in any discussion of any drawbacks to this.
